# How to seclect the second ranked measue value as text

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following table ranked the second and third column using RANKX measure. What I'm trying to achieve is to extract two values from the table below and use both in one text box using CONCATENATE measure:

**First value** : the "Platfrom" name with the highest leads, which is "**FB - Instagram**" using "Rank_By_Leads" column.

**Second value**: the value **6** from the ranked column "Rank_By_Spend".

**Desired output**: **FB - Instagram 6**.

The measures I used to rank the second and third columns

Rank_By_Leads  = RANKX ( ALLSELECTED ( Filter_Platforms[Platform] ), [GA + FBIG Leads], , ASC )
Rank_By_Spend = RANKX ( ALLSELECTED ( Filter_Platforms[Platform] ), [Spend], , ASC )

The output table I have after using the RANKX measure

[image]

**What I have tried**

I managed to extract the first part "FB - Instagram" highlighted in blue using the below measure, but the second part highlighted in red I'm not sure how to extract.

Platform_name_highest_leads = TOPN(
1,
VALUES(Filter_Platforms[Platform]),
[GA + FBIG Leads]
)

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show me the values of the [GA + FBIG Leads] and [Spend] columns via screenshot?